# org.hamcrest.Matchers.any not working in java 8

Tags: java, junit, mockito, hamcrest

Hamcrest Matchers any() is not working in Java 8.

```
when(simpleJdbcCall.execute(Matchers.any(SqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(outputParameters);
```

any() is only working with org.mockito.Matchers which is deprecated.

Is there another way to use this method in Java 8?

Comment: I'm calling this a typo since you imported the wrong class, and there's really not much insight to glean here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use Mockito's `any(Class)`, not Hamcrest's

```
when(simpleJdbcCall.execute(Mockito.any(SqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(outputParameters);
```

You're trying to make Mockito work with Hamcrest's method. It won't work. So change your call from `Matchers.any(SqlParameterSource.class)` to `Mockito.any(SqlParameterSource.class)`.